# Как отсортировать по дате записи?

Tags: wordpress, cms

На главной странице вывожу записи, мне нужно вывести по дате по убыванию:

```
<?php
              if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
              elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
              else { $paged = 1; }
              $posts_on_page = get_option('quantity_posts');

              $args = array(
                            'paged' => $paged,
                            'posts_per_page' => $posts_on_page,
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'orderby' => 'date',
                            'order' => 'desc'
                        );
              $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
              while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
                            get_template_part( 'template-parts/bigpost', get_post_format() );
              endwhile;
          ?>
            <?php               
              the_posts_pagination();
                    wp_reset_postdata(); 
            ?>
```

Но выводит вот так:

```
02.02.2019
02.02.2019
31.01.2019
18.10.2019
```

Comment: Скорее всего, должен помочь параметр 'suppress_filters' => true

Comment: ничего не меняется, все так же

Answer (score 2):

стандартная выборка без ордера будет выводить тот результат, который вы хотите